# Interlocked.CompareExchange if not equal?

Tags: c#, multithreading, atomic, interlocked

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interlocked.CompareExchange<Int> using GreaterThan or LessThan instead of equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042045/interlocked-compareexchangeint-using-greaterthan-or-lessthan-instead-of-equali)

I know that Interlocked.CompareExchange exchanges values only if the value and the comparand are equal,
How to exchange them if they are not equal to achieve something like this ?

```
if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref count, count + 1, max) != max)
    // i want it to increment as long as it is not equal to max
        {
           //count should equal to count + 1
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A more efficient (less bus locking and less reads) and simplified implementation of what Marc posted:

```
static int InterlockedIncrementAndClamp(ref int count, int max)
{
    int oldval = Volatile.Read(ref count), val = ~oldval;

    while(oldval != max && oldval != val)
    {   
        val = oldval;
        oldval = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref count, oldval + 1, oldval);
    }

    return oldval + 1;
}
```

If you have really high contention, we might be able to improve scalability further by reducing the common case to a single atomic increment instruction: same overhead as CompareExchange, but no chance of a loop.

```
static int InterlockedIncrementAndClamp(ref int count, int max, int drift)
{
    int v = Interlocked.Increment(ref count);

    while(v > (max + drift))
    {
        // try to adjust value.
        v = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref count, max, v);
    }

    return Math.Min(v, max);
}
```

Here we allow `count` to go up to `drift` values beyond `max`. But we still return only up to `max`. This allows us to fold the entire op into a single atomic increment in most cases, which will allow maximum scalability. We only need more than one op if we go above our `drift` value, which you can probably make large enough to make very rare.

**In response to Marc's worries about Interlocked and non-Interlocked memory access working together:**

Regarding specifically `volatile` vs Interlocked: `volatile` is just a normal memory op, but one that isn't optimized away and one that isn't reordered with regards to other memory ops. This specific issue doesn't revolve around either of those specific properties, so really we're talking non-Interlocked vs Interlocked interoperability.

The .NET memory model guarantees reads and writes of basic integer types (up to the machine's native word size) and references are atomic. The Interlocked methods are also atomic. Because .NET only has one definition of "atomic", they don't need to explicitly special-case saying they're compatible with each-other.

One thing `Volatile.Read` does *not* guarantee is visibility: you'll always get a load instruction, but the CPU might read an old value from its local cache instead of a new value just put in memory by a different CPU. x86 doesn't need to worry about this in most cases (special instructions like `MOVNTPS` being the exception), but it's a very possible thing with others architectures.

To summarize, this describes two problems that could affect the `Volatile.Read`: first, we could be running on a 16-bit CPU, in which case reading an `int` is not going to be atomic and what we read might not be the value someone else is writing. Second, even if it is atomic, we might be reading an old value due to visibility.

But affecting `Volatile.Read` does not mean they affect the algorithm as a whole, which is perfectly secure from these.

The first case would only bite us if you're **writing** to `count` concurrently in a non-atomic way. This is because what could end up happening is (write A[0]; CAS A[0:1]; write A[1]). Because all of our writes to `count` happen in the guaranteed-atomic CAS, this isn't a problem. When we're just reading, if we read a wrong value, it'll be caught in the upcoming CAS.

If you think about it, the second case is actually just a specialization of the normal case where the value changes between read and write -- the read just happens before we ask for it. In this case the first `Interlocked.CompareExchange` call would report a different value than what `Volatile.Read` gave, and you'd start looping until it succeeded.

If you'd like, you can think of the `Volatile.Read` as a pure optimization for cases of low contention. We could init `oldval` with `0` and it would still work just fine. Using `Volatile.Read` gives it a high chance to only perform one CAS (which, as instructions go, is quite expensive especially in multi-CPU configurations) instead of two.

But yes, as Marc says -- sometimes locks are just simpler!

Comment: Just something to ensure `val != oldval` on the first pass.

Comment: Yes, I agree: much better implementation. I'd still kinda be tempted to do the first read with `Interlocked` to ensure the same isolation rules are applied, but that is very cute

Comment: I don't think you're right about that -- unlike C, in C# "volatile" and "atomic" are actually quite well defined to work together.

Comment: source? I've read the spec several time, and while I know how both are defined individually, I'm not aware of much *together*.

Comment: I'm going to edit the post to explain it, because my response is quite large!

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a "compare if not equal", however: you can test the value yourself first, and then only do the update if you don't get a thread race; this often means you may need to loop if the second test fails. In pseudo-code:

```
bool retry;
do {
    retry = false;
    // get current value
    var val = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref field, 0, 0);
    if(val != max) { // if not maxed
        // increment; if the value isn't what it was above: redo from start
        retry = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref field, val + 1, val) != val;
    }        
} while (retry);
```

But frankly, a lock would be simpler.

Comment: +1 to: "a lock would be simpler"

Comment: what about volatile instead of Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref field, 0, 0)?

Comment: @user1748906 nowhere does it say that `volatile` will respect the same isolation/aromicity rules as `Interlocked`. It'll probably work, but ... I guess it depends how many conflicts you're expecting, like I said already: frankly a lock would be simpler in many cases

Comment: @user1748906 Cory's answer makes much better use of the value when we find we lost in a thread-race, i.e. avoids double reading each iteration.