# C# Max counter with Interlocked

Tags: c#, thread-safety, interlocked

I've been given an assignment to write a max counter class with the following contract:

```
class MaxCounter
{
private int _value = int.MinValue;

public void Max(int value)
{
    if(value > _value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }
}

public int Value => _value;
}
```

The assignment asked to implement a thread-safe, non-locking solution using the `Interlocked` class. I thought about this implementation:

```
public void Update(int value)
    {
        if (value > Interlocked.Read(ref _value))
        {
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref _value, value);
            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} updated counter to {1}.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, value);
        }
    }
```

But I believe it can be improved with the `CompareExchange` function. What do you think?

Comment: Just a nitpick: I think it would be better to match the names of the methods in both of your snippets (your second snippet contains `Update` method instead of `Max`)

Comment: Not only "improved". Your solution is not thread-safe, because between the Read and the Exchange another thread could access and update the object.

Answer (score 2):

### Your current suggested implementation...

... will not work. It's because there's no `Interlocked.Read` method for `Int32`.

Even if there existed such a method for `Int32`, the code would still not work as you expect. You read and update the value not as an atomic operation. After you read the value with `Interlocked.Read` and right before you do an `Interlocking.Exchange`, another thread may be scheduled to run while the current thread may be "postponed", so the second thread will update the counter to some other value. When processor time is given again to the first thread, it will update the counter once more with its own value even if it's lower than `_value`, because the check is already passed.

### Proposed solution

Some quick research lead me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13056904/16759994). Built-in `Interlocked` class does not provide the functionality you require. So, you may use the proposed solution from the answer I linked, or try to implement your own solution with memory barriers, for example (since `Int32` reads and writes are atomic by design).